# Why does JSHint throw a warning if I am using const?

Tags: javascript, node.js, constants, jslint, jshint

This is the error I get when using const:

```
<error line="2" column="1" severity="warning" message="&apos;const&apos; is available in ES6 (use esnext option) or Mozilla JS extensions (use moz)." source="jshint.W104" />
```

My code looks like this:

```
const Suites = {
    Spade: 1,
    Heart: 2,
    Diamond: 3,
    Club: 4
};
```

The code works fine only JSHint is warning me every time.

Comment: I don't see any question in the text, but probably you've already answered it: `"use esnext option"`. And why? Isn't that error message pretty clear? `const` is not standard JS (yet).

Comment: or use eslint instead of jshint

Comment: Not sure if this is new, but the easier solution is to set the ECMAScript level to 6 in the settings. See my full answer below.

Answer (score 671, accepted):

When relying upon ECMAScript 6 features such as `const`, you should set this option so JSHint doesn't raise unnecessary warnings.

<s>/*jshint esnext: true */</s> (**Edit 2015.12.29**: updated syntax to reflect [@Olga's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441803/why-does-jshint-throw-a-warning-if-i-am-using-const/37472928#comment56765015_27442276))

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */

const Suites = {
    Spade: 1,
    Heart: 2,
    Diamond: 3,
    Club: 4
};
```

This option, as the name suggests, tells JSHint that your code uses ECMAScript 6 specific syntax.
http://jshint.com/docs/options/#esversion

**Edit 2017.06.11**: added another option based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37472928/1476885).

While inline configuration works well for an individual file, you can also enable this setting for the entire project by creating a `.jshintrc` file in your project's root and adding it there.

```
{
  "esversion": 6
}
```

Comment: this works ... sure would rather it be some command line parm ! ... hint hint jshint folk

Comment: The documentation now says `Warning This option has been deprecated and will be removed in the next major release of JSHint. Use esversion: 6 instead.` Although my Webstorm built-in plugin does not recognize new option. I ended up specifying both.

Comment: For me its .jshintrc  not .jshint, not sure if there are differences in jshint versions

Comment: Oops. Right you are. Corrected.

Comment: Then restart your Atom, if it is the case

Comment: If anyone else lands here after seeing the error on JSBin, the answer above does not work (It gives the warning: `Bad option: 'esversion'.`)  The old answer does still work there though: `/*jshint esnext: true*/`.  Maybe they are using an old version of something?

Comment: It works! Thanks,  but make sure you should check the location setting for .jshintrc file. I use PhpStorm, which has an option to customize the location of that file.
https://ibb.co/cDRc154
I hope it helps you too!

Answer (score 315):

You can add a file named **.jshintrc** in your app's **root** with the following content to apply this setting for the **whole solution**:

```
{
    "esversion": 6
}
```

[James' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27442276/1476885) suggests that you can add a comment `/*jshint esversion: 6 */` for **each** file, but it is more work than necessary if you need to control many files.

Comment: Is there a configuration for using this? My jshint just ignores what is inside `.jshintrc`.

Comment: @EthanYang, No. There is no extra configuration. Just make sure that the file can be found by JSHint. From docs: `JSHint will start looking for this file in the same directory as the file that's being linted. If not found, it will move one level up the directory tree all the way up to the filesystem root. (Note that if the input comes from stdin, JSHint doesn't attempt to find a configuration file)`

Comment: that worked for me. this is great because we can use different versions across projects - if needed.

Answer (score 101):

I got this same warning when using an export statement. I'm using VS Code and used a similar approach to Wenlong Jiang's solution.

1. User Settings
2. JSHint config
3. `"jshint.config": {}` (Edit)
4. Use **double quotes** when specifying `"esversion"`

   Or copy this snippet into User Settings:

   ```
   "jshint.options": {
     "esversion": 6,
   }
   ```

Creating a `.jshintrc` file isn't necessary if you want to configure the global jshint settings for your editor

Comment: Thank you. Definitely the best answer here for those using visual studio code. 

For ref, User Settings via (Mac:) "Code" > Preferences > Settings.

Comment: Thank you for this additional solution. it is very helpful.

Comment: Great, many thanks. If you use VS Code, this works so well. Also, note that in user settings, this is now  `jshint.config`, just in case.

Answer (score 57):

If you're using VSCode:

**1.**

- Go to **preferences** -> **settings** (`cmd + ,`)
- Type `jshint.options` into the search bar
- Hover over it and click on the pencil icon
- Its now appended on the right side.
- Add `"esversion": 6` to the options object.

---

**2.**

Or simply add this to your user settings:

```
"jshint.options": {
    "esversion": 6
}
```

---

**[UPDATE] new vscode settings**

- Go to **preferences** -> **settings** (`cmd + ,`)
- type `jshint` into search

[image: VSCode Settings]

- continue with step `2.`

Answer (score 38):

I spent ages trying to fix this. Every solution talks about 'setting options'. I don't know what that means. Finally, I figured it out. You can just include a commented out line at the top of the file `/*jshint esversion: 6 */`.

[image: Solution]

Comment: The only problem with doing it this way , as I have found out, is that you have to add the comment to the top of every file you use. A better solution is to create a new file in the root folder of you app named `.jshintrc` and then add the following code to the file ```{
  "esnext": true
}```

Comment: `{ "esnext": true }` is now [deprecated](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#esnext). You should now use `{ "esversion": 6 }` instead.

Comment: I must be using an out-dated version of JSHint, because only by using `"esnext": true` was I able to solve this. `"esversion": 6` had no effect.

Comment: Then upgrade your JShint 

Answer (score 22):

You can specify **esversion:6** inside jshint options object. Please see the image. I am using grunt-contrib-jshint plugin.

[image]

Comment: This works for those using a Grunt. Add this to gruntfile.js

Comment: Thank you ,worked like a charm for me .No need to ignore file(s) and individual implementation of esversioning in exclusive page(s)

Answer (score 12):

Create `.jshintrc` file in the **root** dir and add there the latest js version: `"esversion": 9` and asi version: `"asi": true` (it will help you to avoid using semicolons)

```
{
    "esversion": 9,
    "asi": true
}
```

Answer (score 8):

When you start using ECMAScript 6 this error thrown by your IDE.

**There are two options available:**

if you have only one file and want to use the es6 then simply add below line at the top of the file.

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
```

Or if you have number of js file or you are using any framework(like nodejs express)you can create a new file named `.jshintrc` in your root directory and add code below in the file:

```
{
    "esversion": 6
}
```

If you want to use the es6 version onward for each project you can configure your IDE.

Comment: If this `/*jshint esversion: 6 */` leads to a warning (for example in Sublime Text older versions, like Sublime Text v2), you can then use `/*jshint esnext: true */`.

Answer (score 8):

In your package.json you can tell Jshint to use es6 like this

```
"jshintConfig":{
    "esversion": 6 
}
```

Comment: Answer accepted in April, 2020 for Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 5):

Creating a `.jshintrc` file is ***not necessary***.

If you are using ECMAScript 6 then all you need to do is tell JSHint that:

1. Go to **File > Settings**
2. Navigate to **Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Code Quality Tools > JSHint**.
3. Scroll down to find **Warn about incompatibilities with the specified ECMAScript version**.
4. Click on **Set**.
5. Enter **6** and then press **[Set]**.
6. Click **[OK]**

Comment: I think you should say this is for JetBrains users. I imagine WebStorm or PHPStorm. It worked for me using this last one.

Answer (score 3):

For SublimeText 3 on Mac:

1. Create a .jshintrc file in your root directory (or wherever you prefer) and specify the esversion:

```
    # .jshintrc
    {
      "esversion": 6
    }
```

2. Reference the pwd of the file you just created in SublimeLinter user settings 
   (Sublime Text > Preference > Package Settings > SublimeLinter > Settings)

```
    // SublimeLinter Settings - User
    {
      "linters": {
        "jshint": {
          "args": ["--config", "/Users/[your_username]/.jshintrc"]
        }
      }
    }
```

3. Quit and relaunch SublimeText

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Webstorm and if you don't have your own config file, then just enable `EcmaScript.next` in Relaxing options in in

> Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools |
>   JSHint

See this question [How-do-I-resolve-these-JSHint-ES6-errors](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000112510-How-do-I-resolve-these-JSHint-ES6-errors-?flash_digest=7f9a0f5de48b847a37ee71c787c0d42fa63f2234)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Grunt configuration, You need to do the following steps

Warning message in Jshint:

[image]

**Solution:**

1. Set the jshint options and map the .jshintrc.js file

[image]

2. Create the .jshintrc.js file in that file add the following code

```
{  
  "esversion": 6  
}
```

After configured this, Run again It will skip the warning,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called, say jshint_opts with this content:
{
"esversion": 6
}

Then invoke jshint with something like this command line:

jshint --config jshint_opts lib/*.js

Answer (score 0):

May 2020 Here's a simple solution i found and it will resolve for all of my projects ,on windows if your project is somewhere inside c: directory , create new file .jshintrc and save it in C directory open this .jshintrc file and write `{ "esversion": 6}` and that's it. the warnings should go away , same will work in d directory

[image]

[image]
yes you can also enable this setting for the specific project only by same creating a .jshintrc file in your project's root and adding `{ "esversion": 6}`

Answer (score 0):

To fix this in Dreamweaver CC 2018, I went to 
preferences,
edit rule set - select JS,
edit/apply changes,
find "esnext"  and changed the false setting to true.
It worked for me after hours of research. Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I found that by adding:

```
/* jshint esversion: 8 */
```

(or whatever jshint esversion you need, like 6)

To the top of my .js file satisfies the cause for the warnings.

Answer (score -1):

If using Sublime Text 3:

- Go to **Preferences** -> **Settings**
- Under **Preferences.sublime-settings—User** add **"esversion": 6**

Answer (score -2):

In a new version of Dreamweaver to solve this error

- Go to Edit->Preference->Linting
- And the go-to js Edit rule set
  and past

  "jshintConfig":{
     "esversion": 6 
  }