# ES6 in JShint - .jshintrc has esversion, but still getting warning (using atom)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jshint, atom-editor

I am using atom, and I've tried several different jshint packages and they all give a warning which says

```
"template literal syntax' is only available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6')"
```

I created a top level .jshintrc file (at root), and added the following json:

```
{
  "esversion":6
}
```

However, it is still throwing the same error. Any ideas how to resolve. I've included the link to the [JSHint options](http://jshint.com/docs/options/) page. I'd like to start playing around with ES6 syntax, but would prefer not to have extra warnings.

Thanks SO community!

Comment: If you're starting fresh, the best option would probably be to use ESLint FYI.

Comment: Which jsHint packages have you tried already? There are quite a few of them.  I second @loganfsmyth's comments about using ESLint.

Comment: Simply restarting Atom seems to work.

Comment: In todays world this should probably default to 6 now

Answer (score 131, accepted):

The filename should be `.jshintrc`, and the content is

```
{
  "esversion": 6
}
```

Comment: But like `lvnam96` said below:

You need to set the filetype to JSON, the filename to .jshintrc.

Then close and reopen your JS file.

Answer (score 77):

Instead of creating *.jshintrc* file, you can simply add at the top of your js file:

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
```

Answer (score 11):

We have two choices.

### 1. Using **.jshintrc** file.

Create **.jshintrc** file in root directory and type as below. It applies to all codes

```
{
    "esversion": 6
}
```

> If you're still getting warning, close and re-open your editor.

---

### 2. Using hint.

Type as below at the top of the your code. It applies to just the code.

```
/* jshint esversion: 6 */
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember to close then reopen your JS file / text editor.

Comment: How do I set a filetype to `JSON`?

Comment: @ShimonBrandsdorfer It depends on the code editor you are using.

There are 2 ways in SublimeText 3:
1. Save the file to *.json
2. Select file's type in the bottom right corner (on status bar): there's a button, select JavaScript -> JSON. If there's no status bar at the bottom of the screen, go View -> Show Status Bar.

Comment: @lvnam96 I believe this is wrong. File is not supposed to be named `.jshintrc.json` The options you mention are just for syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Magne Yes, my comment is out of this question's scope because I answered it too late. The main thing is the thread owner updated his question aand I didn't notice his answer too. The accepted answer missed only one thing: reopen the JS file or restart the text editor. I just want to make the solution more clearly ;)
I updated my answer for later coming people.

Answer (score 2):

Has to be the first entry of the jshintrc file.
Doesn't make much sense but that's what fixed it for me.

```
{
"esversion": 6,
"browser": true,
    ...
    ...
    ...
"globals": {... }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a file `.jshintrc` with content

```
{
    "esversion": 6
}
```

Put this file to your **project** root directory. Reopen your js file (no need restart atom). It will work for your current project.

Put this file to your **home** directory (eg: `C`, `D`, `E`, `Desktop`, `Lirary`,...). Reopen your js.file (no need restart atom). It will work for all project inside **home** directory

Answer (score 2):

The config file in which you have enabled es6 should be enabled through your IDE;
eg:for Intellij there's a clear option for adding config files.[JSHint for Intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4gdh.png)

Answer (score 1):

Using the atom packages [linter](https://github.com/steelbrain/linter) and [linter-jshint](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-jshint), I got it to work by uninstalling and then reinstalling the packages and then restarting atom. I did download ESLint and installed it per people's suggestions, looking forward to testing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything, but nothing worked for me.
Adding

```
jshintrc: true,
```

in my grunt config file under `jshint` `options` solved it for me

```
jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: true
        }
    }
```

Or you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42097941/9016028