# jshint 'esversion: 6' issue

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-jshint

I'm having an issue while running the jshint task.  It alerts me to add esversion: 6 to my .jshintrc file.  I entered it like so:

```
{    
    "esversion": 6    
}
```

When that didn't work I tried adding it inline like so:

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
```

However, it's still throwing the same error.  Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use https://eslint.org/ .

Comment: You may have to use `jshint --config .jshintrc` if you're using it as a command-line tool.

Comment: Please try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/75032388/9016028

Answer (score 0):

{
  "esversion": 6
}

is the correct syntax for the .jshintrc file. You probably have the file at the wrong location - it needs to be in the same path the jshint executes from.