# I can't fix the "let" warning in JSHint plugin for vscode in all the new projects I create

Tags: javascript, jshint

When I write:

```
let name = "Henry";
```

The following warning message appear:

```
'let' is available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6') or Mozilla JS extensions (use moz).
```

I don't have any idea what to do for correct that warning. The answers I found are create a file named `.jshintrc` and then add this:

```
{
    "esversion": 6
}
```

The thing is, It just work for the current project I'm programming, If a create a new one, I have to do again the same file. There is another way to do it that apply all the new projects?

Comment: you could `use 'esversion: 6'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does JSHint throw a warning if I am using const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441803/why-does-jshint-throw-a-warning-if-i-am-using-const)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable es6 in your jshint options with the esversion option. If you do not have a .jshintrc file at top level, create one and add this

`{
    "esversion": 6
}`

Optionally, you can add this to the file, but it could get rather annoying if you have to add this to every file

`/* jshint esversion: 6 */`

https://jshint.com/docs/options/#esversion

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a tag to let JSHint know you want to you ES6.

```
/* jshint esversion: 6 */
let name = "Henry";
```